# Google Scripts Index & Matching

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to match Column A and Column D and get the value from Column E and paste the value in Column B. I could do this with VLookUp (Index and Matching) but I need Google script to make this
Please check the scenario and help me on this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in2Ue.png)

Comment: Please have a look at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+VLookUp) first.

Comment: I checked but i didn't find any relevant to my need. Only Matching Scripts are available, No index with Matching scripts available.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify title of question, include [example] of your code, . See [ask]

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see if this answers your additional question. If this is not what you are asking below, kindly show the expected output in your post. If this is exactly what you want to happen, feel free to push the accept button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently started with google apps script and somehow encountered similar to this one. This is the way for me to get the look-up value with a dynamic range. Hope this also helps.

```
function lookUpValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const inputs = ss.getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues();
  const matchValues = ss.getRange(3,4,ss.getLastRow()-2,2).getValues();  
  
  inputs.map(r => r[0]).forEach((input,index) => {
    matchValues.map(r => r[0]).forEach((day,codePos) => {
      if (input === day) {
         ss.getRange("B" + (index + 3)).setValue(matchValues.map(r => r[1])[codePos])           
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: know that you are still checking possible blank cells when using the getLastRow of the sheet on the matchValues right? Also, you are not stopping your inner loop when the value is found, thus running extra loops. Which should be less optimized when running large set of data.

Answer (score 1):

This approach below should populate all rows in one execution. Feel free to modify if you want per cell solution. Answer should descriptive enough but if you have any clarification/questions, feel free to comment below

```
function findItems() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = sheet.getRange('A3:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var days = sheet.getRange('D3:D5').getValues().flat();
  var codes = sheet.getRange('E3:E5').getValues().flat();

  inputs.forEach(function(input, count){
    for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
      if(days[i].trim() == input.trim()){
        sheet.getRange('B' + (count + 3)).setValue(codes[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Sample Output:

[image: sample output]

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you want to compare the current code to the previous one, see the updated output below.

[image: sample output2]

If the current row is same with the row directly above it, it will output `OK` in C, `NOK` if not.

This is the new code:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = sheet.getRange('A3:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var days = sheet.getRange('D3:D5').getValues().flat();
  var codes = sheet.getRange('E3:E5').getValues().flat();

  inputs.forEach(function(input, count){
    for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
      if(days[i].trim() == input.trim()){
        sheet.getRange('B' + (count + 3)).setValue(codes[i]);
        // checks if current code is same with code above it
        if(sheet.getRange('B' + (count + 2)).getValue() == codes[i]){
          sheet.getRange('C' + (count + 3)).setValue('OK');
        }
        else {
          sheet.getRange('C' + (count + 3)).setValue('NOK');
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @Moses. If your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Hello @Nazi, If possible please guide me to use IF statement as well
OLD       NEW       Status
H003      H003        OK
H445       I776        NOK

Here in status I need to compare Old and New , if it's not matching then status should be NOK, If matching it's OK

Comment: hi @Moses, I have updated my answer above for NOK and OK, does it answer your question?